# How to connect to an MSSQL instance in a Docker container from my local machine?

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an instance of MSSQL in a Docker container that is running on my local machine. I used this set of instructions from Microsoft to set up the container, and everything within the container seems to be functioning as expected:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash

I'm trying to connect to the database from my local machine (not in a container) using Python. I've tried various iterations, but the connection script is generally:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'localhost,1433'
database = 'TestDB'
username = 'sa'
password = '<YourStrong@Passw0rd>'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Which generates a pyodbc error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've checked the driver is correct

```
mssql@sql1:/$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

And checked that the ports are open.

Can anyone help with how to make this connection work?

Comment: Does `docker ps -a` show that the `sql1` container is running?

Comment: @GordThompson Yep, the container is running

Comment: How did you actually start the container; what is the `docker run` command?

Comment: Isn't `mssql@sql1:/$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini` inside the SQL Server Docker container? What's installed on the host computer?

Comment: Aside... be aware that `localhost` may not be what you think it is. If IPv6 is your computer's primary protocol then `localhost` will resolve to `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Docker only uses IPv4 connections by default (you can enable IPv6 in the daemon.json file), so try using `server = '127.0.0.1,1433'` in your Python script to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidMaze 
   docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password1" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \
   -d \
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I installed the Microsoft ODBC 17 driver using the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16